# How widespread was the observance of the Jewish Sabbath among Christians during Early Christianity (A.D. 30–324)?

Tags: religion, christianity, religious-history, judaism, 1st-century

**Question**

How widespread was the observance of the [Jewish Sabbath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat) among Christians during [Early Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity#Early_Christianity_(c._31/33%E2%80%93324)) (A.D. 30–324)?

**Further Details**

As a reminder, the [Jewish Sabbath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat) is defined as:

> [...] the Sabbath, is Judaism's day of rest on the seventh day of the week—i.e., Saturday. On this day, religious Jews remember the biblical story describing the creation of the heavens and the earth in six days and look forward to a future Messianic Age. Since the Jewish religious calendar counts days from sunset to sunset, Shabbat begins in the evening of what on the secular calendar is Friday.

And [Early Christianity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christianity#Early_Christianity_(c._31/33%E2%80%93324)) is commonly understood as:

> Early Christianity is generally reckoned by church historians to begin with the ministry of Jesus (c. 27–30) and end with the First Council of Nicaea (325). It is typically divided into two periods: the Apostolic Age (c. 30–100, when the first apostles were still alive) and the Ante-Nicene Period (c. 100–325).[6]

And to be more precise, given that Early Christianity spans about 300 years, it's quite likely that the answer to the question depends on what specific period of time (and location) we are looking at. For this reason, I would rather like to know how the popularity of Jewish Sabbath observance among Christians **has evolved over time**. Was it very popular at the beginning and then gradually became less widespread as time went on? Were there specific places where Christians were more likely to be Sabbath-keepers than in others?

Comment: I think your answer is in your question "and look forward to a future Messianic Age". Christians believed that the Messiah had already come and gone and therefore they were in the Messianic Age. That's the division between Judaism and Christianity. If the age had already come then the practice of observing the Sabbath didn't have the same meaning. I would also suggest that you might want to move this question to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ they may have better answers.

Comment: The famous discussion envolving St Peter and  St Paul is about jewish observances about christians. But, specifically about sabbath, it is hard for some one observe the Sunday mass AND the sabbath at the same time. 2 days of rest per week is just too much for a worker. It is harder to keep this custom than, e.g., eating, praying or dressing like a jew. Consider that one can not have a mass without a priest (one can not choose the day of the main mass alone), and they had to walk up to the mass and back, easily hampering a full day's work.

Comment: This question is equivalent to asking how widespread Torah observance was among [Hellenistic Jews](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism) in pre-Christian times, and how long it took for [Gentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God-fearer) and/or Hellenized Jewish Christians to (vastly) outnumber [Israeli and/or non-Hellenized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_Christian) ones.